# Why can I only open the close/flag dialog every 3 seconds?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, flag-dialog, close-dialog

According to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/349538), the close and flag dialogs can only be loaded every 3 seconds:

> ### Flagging
>
> [...]
>
> - 3 seconds between opening the flag dialog
>
>   [image: Flag Dialog Popup]

> ### Closing
>
> - Can open close dialog once per 3 seconds
>
>   [image: Close Dialog rate limit box]

I've hit this limit quite a few times, usually because I accidentally closed the dialog and wanted to open it again or because the dialog failed to load the first time because of slow internet connection, and I find this limit quite annoying.

I don't understand the purpose of this limit, I've searched on Meta and not found any answer. Usually rate limiting is to prevent abuse of some kind, but I don't see how anybody could abuse the system by simply loading the dialog too fast. Besides, since the same user can only flag every 5 seconds, removing this limit wouldn't prevent any abuse since for example a bot that is programmed to flag a lot of posts at once would still hit the limit for flagging every 5 seconds.

Could someone please explain the purpose of this limit?

Comment: I'd imagine it because it has to do a calculation on the server to find out how many flags you have left if this wasn't rate limited it could be abused. Would be nice to know if that is the reason why, as a lot of actions on this site are rate limited.

Comment: DoS attack and bot protection, probably.  There are non-trivial dbase queries behind it so without protection it would be easy to bring the entire site to its knees.  What are you going to differently now that you know?

Comment: The system also needs to check whether to warn about your last declined flag if needed, to warn you that you might be approaching a ban or to tell you, you're in a ban and you can't flag for n days... 3 seconds seems more than reasonable for the occasional slow connection or "oops I closed the window by mistake" you describe. Patience is a virtue and all that :)

Comment: Also thinking about it some more... The state of the post (closed, deleted, locked, age in case of VLQ) and any existing flag(s) you have or had on it need to be checked to determine what flag options are available at the time you open it.

Comment: The annoying part is that it starts the count over every time you click the link, so if you click it once, use it, then click it again after 2.5 seconds, and get that tooltip error, then wait 1.5 or 2 seconds, you get that tooltip error again. I know it's not the easiest thing to fix, but it's still pretty annoying.

Comment: Ideally, the button would recognize that the window was opened less than 3 seconds ago and just reopen the window that it loaded previously. I mean: How much could change within 3 seconds? If the state wasn’t cleared immediately when the window is closed, it could be easily be reconstructed without having to hit the server again.