# 5 seconds is too long, but if it must be, then give me a visual cue

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, rate-limiting

[image]

I don't know how many times I've tried to flag two "Thank you" comments in a row only to get the error message above. Then I have to go through the whole process all over again of clicking the flag button, choosing the "no longer needed" option, and clicking the "Flag Comment" button.

If it were 3 seconds I probably wouldn't run into the error. But apparently it is something about [giving the system time to do its work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355200/why-can-i-only-open-the-close-flag-dialog-every-3-seconds#comment505010_355200).

So if the [rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/284743) has to stay at 5 seconds, it would be nice to have a visual cue to know when the time is up and I won't be penalized (ie, made to go through the whole process again) for clicking the "Flag Comment" button.

It seems like a good UX decision would be to make it impossible to do something you are not allowed to do. The button is already disabled until you choose a flag reason. Just keep it that way until the 5 seconds are up.

[image]

Comment: *"If it were 3 seconds I probably wouldn't run into the error"* - FWIW, the rate limit on *opening* the flag dialog is 3 seconds. I regularly run into it, but only *because* of the 5 second rate limit: I flag a comment, check that I want to flag the next comment too, open the flag dialog and click to flag, get blocked from flagging due to the 5 second limit, go to *re*-open the flag dialog and get blocked *again* by the 3 second limit.

Comment: The limit is fundamentally ill-conceived because if you're flagging multiple comments, you usually ***need*** to read over the thread, figure out what to delete, then flag en-masse. Doing anything else runs the risk that you'll leave orphaned, now-incoherent replies to comments that you got deleted - or that you'll be forced to get those *replies* deleted too even if they had valuable content. The rate limit seems to assume that you read each comment in full, consider it, flag, and then move onto the next one... but in many circumstances, doing that is *wrong* and will inevitably do damage.

Comment: @MarkAmery I actually disagree. I read a thread, figure what to flag, then proceed to flag each one of them, and reread each comment to make sure it really is a valid flag. I totally stand with the five seconds limit. I question your assumption that the limit assumes that we would not read over all the thread, and am not sure how you get there from a simple 5 seconds limit.

Comment: Considering the second-class-citizen status comments have, it'll be interesting to see whether _destroying_ them is considered an important function by the team...

Comment: *"I don't know how many times I've tried to flag two "Thank you" comments"* - In response to that and being somewhat off-topic to the actual question: What is so wrong about people saying "thank you"? If we can't appear to be "human", then we're just as emotionless as machines. There's nothing wrong with being nice. There are far more comments that need not be said in the first place, some just being bad advice or know nothing on the subject at hand.

Comment: If you are going to flag comments en masse, just raise a custom mod flag and ask that the thread be cleaned up.

Comment: Relevant: [Can we remove the 5 second rate limiting on comment flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299103)

Comment: Personally, I agree with @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. If you want a large number of comments pruned, such that the 5-second rate-limit would be annoying, then just raise a custom moderator flag on the post and ask that the comments be pruned. This is *much* easier for me to deal with, and moderators don't have annoying rate-limits when removing comments. Sure, I have to read the whole comment thread, but I do that anyway. Unfortunately, opinions among moderators seem to differ here, and some prefer that you flag comments individually. I think it hinges on whether we read the full thread or individual comments.

Comment: But, either way, I have to agree that changing the enabled state of the submit button would make for a *far* better user experience. You'd still have to account for the smartasses who would try and edit the HTML to re-enable the button (via a userscript so it would be done faster than the 5-second rate limit), but those people could still get the red error box.

Comment: @CodyGray, if that is the case, then why not mention that in the red box as an alternative action to waiting? "If this sequence of comments need moderator attention, please raise a custom mod flag and explain why"

Comment: @CodyGray, I had always just assumed that flagging an individual comment was easier for the moderators. Some of the simple "thank you" ones disappear automatically after I flag them. I've only been flagging the whole post if all of the comments could be deleted. I'll consider a request to "prune" the comments next time.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I personally am not flagging the "thank you" comments as something bad. I even like getting them. But after the poster has seen them they become noise, drowning out some potentially more useful comments. I only flag them to clean them up.

Comment: Anyone wondering what @CodyGray means when he says "opinions among moderators seem to differ here" should see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338911/1709587.

Comment: The only thing that prevent me from running my comment flag script. (Currently I set a 6 seconds interval for each flag)

Comment: I agree; I don't see the logic behind making people wait 3 seconds to open the flag dialog and then wait *another* 2 seconds to submit it, rather than just making people wait 5 seconds to open the flag dialog. It seems needlessly complex and unfriendly/confusing from a UX perspective.

Comment: Same goes for editing comments.

Comment: why did they make it 5 seconds? because they couldn't make it 10 seconds

Answer (score 121):

What I would like to see is the ability to select multiple comments in a conversation, then flag them all in one go (and possibly show up as a single flag to the handler). Flagging 7 comments in a row has always felt like a misuse of the system, even if it isn't, so multiflagging makes it more efficient for both the flagger and the handler.

While this doesn't implement your suggestion, it solves the root issue and makes your suggestion unnecessary.

Comment: That ability already exists. All you have to do is raise a custom mod flag and ask that the thread be pruned.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not really. The mod still needs to go through all the comments and figure out which ones to remove. Every other mod seems to have a different preference about whether they prefer a custom post flag or multiple comment flags. This problem needs to be fixed properly at some point.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Also, I think (but I may be wrong) that enough "no longer needed" flags on a specific comment will automatically delete the comment without any moderator having to be involved, but a custom flag won't do that so a moderator will have to manually delete the comments. So there would be a risk wasting a moderator's time to do something that the system could do itself.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: [That's correct, sort of.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237368) Custom comment flags don't count as delete votes, *unless* the comment happens to contain one of the semi-secret bad words or phrases that cause it to be auto-deleted as soon as it's flagged even once. Or at least, that's how it worked back in 2014 when I tested it.

Comment: I made a feature request for this sort of thing a while back. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352524/how-to-flag-everything

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322702/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-handling-large-amounts-of-trashy-comments-on-a

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I noticed that. I just tested posting a comment with bad words with a sock puppet and flagging it with a custom flag, and it got deleted immediately.

Answer (score 3):

As of v1.50, my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script now contains [an implementation of this feature.](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/68cdb600b9a0e4901790585259216567ed548e33/SOUP.user.js#L1633)  It works pretty much exactly like you suggested: if you load a flag dialog within 5 seconds of having submitted an earlier flag, it "super-disables" the submit button in the dialog until the five second timeout is over.

(I'm not actually sure if the server-side rate limiting code has separate timers for comment and post flags, or just one shared timer for both, but to be safe, the SOUP code assumes the latter.  It also treats close votes the same as flags, because they use a very similar-looking AJAX request.  I'm not actually 100% sure if close votes are subject to the same [5 second rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) as flags are, and if so, whether it's the same timer or not, but it seemed safer to assume that they are.)

The implementation is a little bit ugly due to the fact that the SE dialog code itself enables and disables the submit button depending on whether you have a valid flag / close reason selected, and the SOUP code needs to suppress that while also keeping track of the state the button *should* have when the timer expires.  But it seems to work.  Of course, this would be a lot simpler and easier to implement by directly modifying the SE dialog handling code, but I can't do that from a user script.

Also note that the SOUP implementation only tracks the timeout within a single page.  If you load multiple posts in separate browser tabs and try to flag them all quickly enough, you can still hit the server-side timeout.  Honestly, at that point I'd consider that to be your own fault.