# Discrepancy between rate limit for opening flag dialogue and actual flagging

Tags: support, feature-request, flags, rate-limiting

There is a rate limit on flagging (whether we like it or not).

Today I participated in some comments on a question here on meta, where I asked the OP for some clarification. He provided the desired clarification, and put that in the appropriate place (the question).

So I thought I'd do some housekeeping and clean up the comments thread. I deleted my own redundant comments and flagged those from OP that were no longer needed, and are now out of sync in the conversation seeing I deleted my own comments.

There were two comments to flag and I hit the annoying rate limit of opening the flag dialogue only once every 3 seconds. So I waited another second and opened the flag dialogue on the second comment, only to be smacked in the face with another rate limit on the actual flagging (once every 5 seconds).

To my knowledge there is no other way to flag a comment other then opening the flag dialogue, so I suggest we either:

- Remove the rate limit from the flag dialogue
- Remove the flagging rate limit

If there are some (technical) concerns regarding this I propose, as a short-sighted solution, we make both rate limits 3 seconds.

Comment: Apart from this FR, isn't it easier for a mod reviewing your flags to have your existing comments to verify your claim "comments are obsolete is true? I always kept my comments and custom flagged a single comment with an explanation which comments were included in the discussion and can now be deleted. I wonder which approach is the better/correct one.

Comment: I sometimes notice near-immediate removal of flagged comments when I delete(d) my own comments.

Comment: I'm not saying that flagging with your "style" would be wrong, I meant in a point of view of an moderator who needs to review these flag, which approach is the better for them. Just asking out of curiosity :)

Comment: @Tom We can see the deleted comments with a click of a button, so it doesn't matter too much either way. If there's a bunch of comments needing to be deleted, it's fine to raise a custom flag on the post requesting it. But yeah, I do agree the rate limit is too strict for comment flags, it frustrates me when I flag on other sites on the network, too

Comment: @Rob Thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: @Luuklag That may be because those comments have some form of the phrase "Thank you", for example "Thanks", etc.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the multiple alternatives proposed by Luuklag, I do support the last one:

> I propose [...] we make both rate limits 3 seconds.

This would quickly and easily address [multiple complains](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358862/5-seconds-is-too-long-but-if-it-must-be-then-give-me-a-visual-cue) on this specific rate limit of 5 seconds. It would address a moderator-tools request without much efforts and risk. To put it in perspective, we're talking about an already [capped number of flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900): 10 flags a day if you've never flagged before, and up to 100 flags a day when you have many previously accepted flags.

As for reducing it under 3 seconds, that's more tricky and would face diverse practical issues:

> The system also needs to check whether to warn about your last declined flag if needed, to warn you that you might be approaching a ban or to tell you, you're in a ban and you can't flag for n days. [...]
>   [--  Jon Clements♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355200/why-can-i-only-open-the-close-flag-dialog-every-3-seconds#comment505010_355200)

Overall, going with a 3 seconds rate limit instead of 5 seconds rate limit sounds like the reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you can wait with the dialog box *open* when you're too quick flagging a subsequent comment. Just hit the `Submit` button again after a couple of seconds...

Comment: That might certainly be an option, but why should it be like that. It would be far more user friendly to sync the rate limits. Avoiding hitting two red boxes in a row.