# Fix timeout for the "You may only open the close dialog every 3 seconds" notification

Tags: feature-request, status-review, design, vote-to-close, rate-limiting

Several of the interactions with the site are rate-limited and will bring up a warning notice if you do them repeatedly. For example, you can only flag comments every 3 seconds.

Typically, these notices stay up for as long as you are required to wait; so, for example, if you get a notification when attempting to flag a comment, just wait until the notice disappears, and you know you can try again without getting the notification.

When you vote to close and select the wrong button in the dialog, a common flow is to cancel the dialog with <kbd>Esc</kbd> (or clicking <kbd>Cancel</kbd> if you need a mouse to communicate with your computer) and then reopen the dialog. However, this action too is throttled, and will produce a warning message:

[image]

However, unlike many other notices of this kind, this one stays up for much longer than 3 seconds.  By informal timing, I get 20 seconds for this particular notification.

Could the notification please disappear after 3 seconds?
(Or, if 3 seconds is too short for people to see the notification, maybe just make the period 5 seconds. Tangentially, see also *[5 seconds is too long, but if it must be, then give me a visual cue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358862/5-seconds-is-too-long-but-if-it-must-be-then-give-me-a-visual-cue/362418#362418*.)) Or, if you can, just don't rate limit this particular feature.

In other words, the design where the notification disappears when time is up is an obscure but helpful usability hint; I want it for this notification, too, if indeed it has to remain rate-limited.

Comment: Otherwise instead of showing an error message at all, maybe just open the same close vote dialog as the one that was loaded 3 seconds ago.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I would find it annoying

Comment: @Konrad If you dismissed it and tried to open it again, that's exactly the behavior you want. That's what removing the throttling entirely would accomplish. Opening the dialog when you didn't request it would be annoying, but that is not what is being discussed here.

Comment: What I imagine @DonaldDuck is saying is, if you did some moderately expensive operation to make the pseudo-dialog appear the first time, cache the results if it's dismissed so that it can be brought up again with almost no cost. (Though perhaps I'm just demonstrating my ignorance of how this works under the hood.)

Comment: @tripleee Correct. According to the comments to [Why can I only open the close/flag dialog every 3 seconds?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355200/4284627), the reason why this is rate limited at all is to prevent attacks where bots would open the dialog very often in order to overload the server. If the results are cached client side, there would be no need for requests at all the second time the dialog is opened, removing the need for rate limiting.